# VLookup with requirements

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm not sure the best way to word this but here it goes:

I have 3 open workbooks; one with medical codes and a corresponding modifier, the second with the medical code and how much it pays with each of the modifiers and three is my separate workbook where the vlookup exists.

Right now I have the vlookup looking in my 1st workbook finding the medical code and finding it in the second workbook and outputting the price at which it pays. Is there a way to add criteria? As in, find the medical code in book 1 and if there is a modifier in the column next to it find that corresponding price in book 2?

Example right now I have medical code:

11111 in column I
And modifier 99 in column L

Book 2 will have a price for code 11111 when it has a modifier 99,98 and non modifier each in their own row is there a way to return just the price with modifier 99?

Answer (score 0):

Abandon Vlookup and learn to use Index and Match in it's place.

Match can be used to locate the row number the lookup value is found in another sheets column. The index function can return the value or the value a couple of columns over. You can use a second match function to locate the modifier code also.